# iPhone : How to detect the dismiss of a modal view in Twitter API?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter

In my app, I am having a need for Twitter API integration.

I want to detect the dismissing of the modal view which comes up for the authentication and want to display alert when that modal view is dismissed.

I found the code for presentModalViewController in the file but could not get dismissModalViewController code at any place.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect when a modal view controller has been dismissed, you can implement

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

If implemented, this method will be called as soon as the view has, well, disappeared...

More details at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear:

OR

An alternative is creating a delegate protocol and implementing a method that gets called when the login process has concluded. This gives you more flexibility as you can call different methods depending on whether the login was successful or not etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot Rog. You really are very patient and kind in answering my silly questions.:) Thanks.There can be only one vote up that can be given by me :( ... 10 votes up for you :)

Comment: @Parth no worries mate, happy to help whenever I can :-)

Comment: Be careful: this method does not mean the modal was dismissed, it means it is no longer what the user is seeing. It will also fire if the modal is covered up by, for instance, a second modal. When that second modal is dismissed, the original modal is still there. I have been searching for a signal that really means the modal was actually dismissed, and I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

How do you dismiss the modal view?  Do you do something like:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewController:authenticationViewController animated:YES]
```

If you do do this, do you call it from an IBAction triggered by clicking a "login" button or the didEnterOnExit event in the authentication text fields?

If so, why not display the alert in this IBAction?

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, so if this doesn't help, if you could be more specific, I can be more helpful.

-HT

Comment: Thanks HTR but I dont use this dismissViewController method. Rog has answered my question. :) Thanks anyways for answering :)